# How to achive PLSQL procedure overloading package

Tags: plsql

I have a use case where a package has 2 procedure with the same name and argument, one as `CHAR` type and another is `VARCHAR2` type.

How to call tham?

Answer (score 0):

For PL/SQL the package spec and body compiles ok.

But at runtime the 2 procedures are the same and there is no way to distinguish because CHAR type and VARCHAR2 type are of the same datatype family.

For example:

```
create or replace package pk_over
is
  procedure pr_text(p_isbCaracter char);

  procedure pr_text(p_isbCaracter  varchar2);
End;



create or replace package body pk_over
is
  procedure pr_text(p_isbCaracter char)
  is
  Begin
    Dbms_Output.Put_Line('Soy PR_TEXT parámetro CHAR="'||p_isbCaracter||chr(34));
  End pr_text;
  --
  procedure pr_text(p_isbCaracter  varchar2)
  is
  Begin
    Dbms_Output.Put_Line('Soy PR_TEXT parámetro VARCHAR2="'||p_isbCaracter||chr(34));
  End pr_text;
  --
End pk_over;
```

An you call with:

```
Declare
  sbVar2    varchar2(20);
Begin
  sbVar2:='Texto 1';
  pk_over.pr_text(sbVar2);
End;
```

The error at runtime is:

> PLS-00307: too many declarations of 'PR_TEXT' match this call

So you don't need the 2 procedures, only one.